# Varying in sending serials to Arduino

Tags: arduino, processing, kinect, led

I'm building a LED grid in octagon shape. It has 8 sides that are triggered by the X axis of someone on a Kinect.

It sends 8 serials to Arduino to trigger the leds on one side of the octagon. These leds are all (255,0,0) Red.

I want to make it so I can switch between blue, green and red in processing. Does anybody have any tips on how to do something like this?

I was thinking of maybe creating three buttons (R,G,B) and using mousepressed to vary between the serials that are being send to Arduino

The only problem is I am a bit new to processing. does someone know how to tackle this?

Here is my code for processing

```
import org.openkinect.freenect.*;
import org.openkinect.processing.*;
import processing.serial.*;


// The kinect stuff is happening in another class
KinectTracker tracker;
Kinect kinect;
Serial myPort;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  kinect = new Kinect(this);
  tracker = new KinectTracker();
  String portName = Serial.list()[2]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {

  tracker.track();
  tracker.display();

  PVector v1 = tracker.getPos();
  fill(50, 100, 250, 200);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(v1.x, v1.y, 50, 50);




   //1
    if (v1.x > 0 && v1.x < 80 ){
    println('8');
    //rect(0,200,200,200);
    myPort.write('8'); }
    //println('0'); }

    //2
  if (v1.x > 80 && v1.x < 160){
    println('7');
    myPort.write('7'); }   
 //3
   if (v1.x > 160 && v1.x < 240 ){
    println('6');
    myPort.write('6'); }

    //4
   if (v1.x > 240 && v1.x < 320 ){
    println('5');
   myPort.write('5'); }

    //5
   if (v1.x > 320 && v1.x < 400 ){
    println('4');
    myPort.write('4'); }

    //6
   if (v1.x > 400 && v1.x < 480 ){
    println('3');
    myPort.write('3'); }

    //7
   if (v1.x > 480 && v1.x < 560 ){
    println('2');
    myPort.write('2'); }

    //8
   if (v1.x > 560 && v1.x < 620 ){
    println('1');
    myPort.write('1'); }
}
```

Here is Arduino code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_PIN     6
#define NUM_LEDS    360

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup()
{
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  FastLED.clear();
  FastLED.show();
}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    int incomingByte = Serial.read();

    if (incomingByte > '0' && incomingByte < '9')
    {
      FastLED.clear();   //  <-----<<<<    USE clear
    }


    if (incomingByte == '1')
    for(int i = 0; i<=44; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
      }
    else if (incomingByte == '2')
    for(int i = 45; i<=89; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
    } 
    else if (incomingByte == '3')
    for(int i = 90; i<=134; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
    }

  else if (incomingByte == '4')
    for(int i = 135; i<=179; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (incomingByte == '5')
    for(int i = 180; i<=224; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255,0, 0);
    }
    else if (incomingByte == '6')
    for(int i = 225; i<=269; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (incomingByte == '7')
    for(int i = 270; i<=314; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (incomingByte == '8')
    for(int i = 315; i<=359; i++){
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);

 }

    FastLED.show();
  }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you need resources for making a GUI in Processing, I've had a luck with [ControlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/).  There's loads of examples, and it's a really sleek aesthetic.  You should be able to use the examples there to change the value that you're sending over serial to choose your color.